# Inno-Setup Installer does not dynamically choose the language of the Windows OS

Tags: inno-setup

I have an application which runs on Windows.

My requirement is: when the language on the Windows is configured to Portuguese, the installer should display text in Portuguese language by default, without showing any select language option.

Similarly, when running on Windows configured with English, it should pick up English and so on.

Currently, as my language in `default.isl` under `[langOptions]` is English, It pickups up English. Even on Portuguese Windows machine it displays English only.

My script is as below:

```
[Setup]
AppId={{A33BA940-B460-FFFF-EFF3-1DDCE7083726}
AppName=Software Updater
AppVersion=2.6.3
DefaultDirName={pf}\Software Updater
DefaultGroupName=Software Updater
OutputDir=C:\Users\vinayb\Documents\SU_installer  
OutputBaseFilename=Software Updater 64bit - version 2.6.3
SetupIconFile=C:\Vinay\Installer\2.6.3\Installer files\SU_256px.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon=C:\Vinay\Installer\2.6.3\Installer files\SU_256px.ico
UninstallDisplayName=Software Updater
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
WizardSmallImageFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup5\WizModernSmallImage-IS.bmp
WizardImageFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WizModernImage-IS.bmp
LanguageDetectionMethod=uilanguage
ShowLanguageDialog=no

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\EnglishUS.isl"
Name: "en_GB"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\EnglishUK.isl"
Name: "brazilianportuguese"; MessagesFile:"compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl"
Name: "catalan"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Catalan.isl"
Name: "corsican"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Corsican.isl"
Name: "czech"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Czech.isl"
Name: "danish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Danish.isl"
Name: "dutch"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Dutch.isl"
Name: "finnish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Finnish.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "german"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"
Name: "greek"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Greek.isl"
Name: "hebrew"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Hebrew.isl"
Name: "hungarian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Hungarian.isl"
Name: "italian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Italian.isl"
Name: "japanese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl"
Name: "norwegian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Norwegian.isl"
Name: "polish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Polish.isl"
Name: "portuguese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Portuguese.isl"
Name: "russian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
Name: "scottishgaelic"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\ScottishGaelic.isl"
Name: "serbiancyrillic"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\SerbianCyrillic.isl"
Name: "serbianlatin"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\SerbianLatin.isl"
Name: "slovenian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Slovenian.isl"
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"
Name: "ukrainian"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Ukrainian.isl"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Example\Software Updater\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Language"; ValueData: "{language}"
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Example\Software Updater\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Version"; ValueData: "2.6.3"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files\Software Updater\Software Updater.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files\Software Updater\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Software Updater"; Filename: "{app}\Software Updater.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Software Updater}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Software Updater"; Filename: "{app}\Software Updater.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Software Updater"; Filename: "{app}\Software Updater.exe"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\Uninstall.bat"; StatusMsg: "Deleteing temporary files and directory...";

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{tmp}\global"
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}"
```

My `default.isl` file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5` has the following entries.

```
[LangOptions]
LanguageName=English
LanguageID=$0409
LanguageCodePage=0
```

Any way around this?

Comment: So your current Windows language in not English, you have the very same language configured in your installer's script `[Languages]` section, and yet the installer uses English? Show us your script.

Comment: I have edited the question with my script changes.

Comment: Your code works for me. Tested on Windows 7 x64. I go to *Control Panel* > *Clock, Language, and Region* > *Change display language* > Select *Czech* (*čeština*) in *Choose display language*, log off, log on, and run an installer built from your code. It starts in Czech. [See a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk29F.png). When I switch back to *English*, the installer starts in English. [See a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBJsr.png).

Comment: Thanks so much. Probably its not working as we are using Windows 7 x64 Professional Version. could you please confirm if your PC has HOME edition of Windows ??

Comment: No, I'm using Windows 7 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Make sure you uninstall the application first. You may have some remnant of preferences from some old development version of the installer, that had the language selection dialog enabled yet, that overrides the detected language.